# SQL Server - Table cleanup not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

I am working on a large database (32 Gb) containing application and services logs and traces going back a few years that I want to trim down to only a month's worth of data.

We already have a stored proc and job that can be run to do so, with variable retention, but when I ran it for the past day it has not worked. I've also tried a straight delete statement

```
delete from [INFRAICC 2.0].[css].[DatabaseTrace] where time < DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
```

but I am getting the same results:

The transaction log fills up, but the database itself does not get any smaller. 
I suspect possibly an access issue (though it's writing the log fine) but I cannot find any way to confirm this, or if there is any other possible reason.

Comment: Has the data been deleted? Do you get anything if you run select query? Delete some data doesn't mean the database will be smaller

Comment: you may have to delete the records in bulk fashion.  If the records to be deleted much more than you want to keep, perhaps it's faster to move the records you want to keep in a new table, drop the old table and rename the new table back.

Comment: The data is not deleted - I've validated as much. Any tips on bulk moving the small subset of records I want to keep to a new, identical table?

Comment: If you run your DELETE statement as a SELECT statement, do you get records? Maybe there's just something wrong with comparing the [time] field to the DATEADD?

Comment: It does return (a lot of) results. Though it failed to order them as desired, possibly due to the t-log filling up the HDD.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server will reserve space on the drive and will not release that when data is deleted unless you tell it to. It just keeps it reserved with the expectation that you'll need it again. Read up on `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` and review the recommendations - you don't want to over-shrink it because there's a performance hit when it has to go and reserve more space, so you don't want it doing that all the time.

Comment: I am aware - the records are not being deleted at all (confirmed with a select query searching for the oldest entries). The free space for the database is at 0%